# How I can resolve this limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I want to know if this series: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ {\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{(n+1)}}{n}}$$ converges or not, so I applied Leibniz's criterion.

I know that the terms are decreasing in absolute value, I am left to know if their limit is 0.

However, I do not know how I can resolve this limit: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{(n+1)}}{n}$$

I tried to solve it but I can't get to the end because when I do the limit I try to apply logarithms, but $(-1)^{n + 1}$ is a problem for me.

Could you help me, explaining very detailed in order to understand it.

Thank you very much and sorry for my English.

Comment: Series or sequence?

Comment: It is a Serie, sorry

Comment: Also, the limit is necessary for convergence, but not sufficient.

Comment: Put \ before sum and lim, and they'll come out nice.

Comment: For Leibniz, you need (i) $a_n\to0$ and $a_n>a_{n+1}$ where $a_n=\sqrt{n+1}/n$. You don't need to worry about the $(-1)^{n+1}$ factor.

Comment: Why I did not worry about \(-1)^{n+1} factor?

Comment: The other factor goes to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\frac {\sqrt {x+1}} x$ is decreasing on $[0, \infty)$ and tends to $0$ as $x \to \infty$ so Alternating Series Test shows that the series is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

To add some more detail, as already noticed $$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n}=\sqrt{\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}}$$

is strictly deacreasing since it is a composition of $\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}$, which is strictly decreasing with $\sqrt{x}$ which is strictly increasing.

Therefore we can apply [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).